# Auto Save PDF with Naming VBA for Excel, Must work on both Mac and PC

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to make an auto-save macro that will work on both PC and Mac (currently a shared OneDrive holds the Excel spreadsheet, both Mac and PC users). I can get it to save to desktop for either/or, but not both. Current xxxxxxx represents my local machine (Mac). Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Sub PDF()
'
' PDF Macro
'

'

Dim Sname

Sname = Cells(11, 2).Value

    ActiveSheet.Application.GetSaveAsFilename Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/INVOICE - " & Sname & ".pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

I've tried several options found online, but I'm relatively new at this and just can't seem to get the naming convention rolled into the code properly.

Comment: Er, why not use `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` to let the user select the path and name? This will work in both Win and MAC

Comment: Part of the purpose of the macro is to auto insert the invoice number into the name.  It would be ok if the user selected the path, but I would like the naming to be automatic.

Comment: Also want the file to default to PDF.

Comment: RESOLVED - I must have mistyped something with previous attempts. I just removed the Path before INVOICE. File saves to Desktop on Mac and Documents on PC, but that is workable. Thanks for the feedback everyone.